# How to add missing data from one dataframe to another?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am working on a project that requires to fill out missing data from one Excel sheet to another. For example:

```
table A:
card name address zipcode
123  steve  chicago  60601
321  Joy    New York   10083
222  Andy   San Francisco  43211


table B:
card name address zipcode
321  steve  nan      nan
123  Joy     nan      nan
123  nan    nan      nan
```

For this project, I need fill out table B according to table A. I do have idea about using Excel `VLOOKUP` function to fill out all of columns, but I guess if the number of data file getting huge in future, then I may use python to do this. (eg, same data format but from different branches)

In Python, the `merge` function can do this but it takes too much time. Is there any useful function in pandas, numpy, or any other third-party library that can help me do this? Thanks all!

Here is what I have tried:

```
df.merge(table A, table B, on = 'card', how = 'right')
```

it does work but I have to rename columns to match each features. And I also know we can do this on SQL very fast and effiency, just wanna do this on python :)

Comment: Regardless of how you do it, you're going to need some kind of unique identifier column/ combination of columns to use as an index.

Comment: @Linden thx for your reply, Yes, like database, the card will be unique identifier in this case.

Comment: I asked because card is not unique in table B and Steve and Joy have different cards in table A and B.

Comment: @Linden sorry for my mistake, since I need fillout data from table A to table B, then card 123 from table B should be fillout with steve's info

Comment: there are two lines with card 123 in table B. Should they both have Steve's data? Do you want to duplicate the data in table A for all rows in table b with card 123?

Answer (score 1):

Of course pandas library can do this and more. I am currently writing a business intelligence program. And I do a lot of operations like this with pandas
There are many ways to do this, but since I don't see your code, you can do it in the simplest and most understandable way. Turn at the point where you are stuck.thank you

```
    searchdata = Atabledata[['name','adress','zipcode']]

    for i in search['name']:
            Btabledata.loc[Btabledata['name']== i, Btabledata['adress']] = Atabledata['adress']
            Btabledata.loc[Btabledata['name'] == i, Btabledata['zipcode']] = Atabledata['zipcode']

    print(Btabledata)
```

Comment: here is what I tried :df.merge(table A, table B, on = ['card'])

Comment: So I do not understand exactly what you want. Do you want to do this in the same table? You must share your full code

Comment: @ user14410167 just like what I mentioned in context. I want match&fill out data from table A to table B. table contains all of information which B does not. In this case, card should be unquie indentifier can help us to do this job, your anwser is pretty straightforward but i guess we may has 3rd library can do this more easier?